# How to recognize Host Monitor from a Hyper-V VM?

Tags: external-display, resolution, hyper-v

I have a monitor with resolution 1280*720 which i want to set in the Hyper-V windows Server 2008R2 VM i have been using for Development, but i  don't how to add this monitor to my VM or recognize this from my VM. I searched internet but couldn't find out.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Shihab

Answer (score 0):

When you plug a second monitor, assuming your hardware supports it, you should see it in the "Screen resolution" control panel applet, or you can try hitting "Windows+P" - it would show you a popup window where you can change this.

Comment: I can see it on the host, but i can see it on Virtual Machines running on the Host?

Comment: It seem I misunderstood you.
What I've offered you is good if you want one screen for viewing Hyper-V machines and another for your host computer (after plugging the two monitors and configuring them as extended desktops you can easily transfer windows).
Anyway, I don't think it's possible (yet) to fully expose the physical video card to the Hyper-V VM (same goes with VMWare and VBox), but you might find something useful here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2012/02/17/remotefx-with-hyper-v-is-a-serious-business-tool-for-games.aspx.

Comment: didn't help..this is not what i was looking for :(